# How do I configure Rails to disable sending real emails out while in staging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm on Heroku, and emails don't get sent out in development, but are properly being sent in production.  I'd like to run a seperate staging instance on Heroku, but don't want emails being sent out (just to a log).

Answer (score 18):

This line in test.rb tells ActionMailer not to deliver emails:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

Instead, they are accumulated in the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.

You'll need to set up a staging environment for your application and configure Heroku to use that environment on your staging instance.

Answer (score 12):

Applications that use the Mail gem (including rails >= 3.0 projects) can use the safety_mailer gem.  Specify a domain (or set of domains, or magic word in email address) email is allowed to go to, and email to all other domains is silently dropped.

https://github.com/cluesque/safety_mailer

Add the gem to your `Gemfile`, specifying groups (probably not production) to include it in.

```
gem "safety_mailer", :group => :development
```

Don't forget to `bundle install` to install

In your environment file `config/environments/development.rb` configure it, and some regular expressions.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :safety_mailer
config.action_mailer.safety_mailer_settings = {
  allowed_matchers: [ /mydomain.com/, /mytestacct@gmail.com/, /super_secret_test/ ],
  delivery_method: :smtp,
  delivery_method_settings: {
    :address => "smtp.mydomain.com",
    :port => 25,
    :domain => "mydomain.com",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "mydomain_mailer@mydomain.com",
    :password => "password"
  }
}
```

... and now, email to anyone@mydomain.com, mytestacct@gmail.com, bob+super_secret_test@yahoo.com all get sent
and email to other recipients (like the real users in the production database you copied to a test server) is suppressed.

Answer (score 10):

You might be interested in [mailtrap.io](http://mailtrap.io) (**disclaimer:** I am affiliated with this product). It is a perfect tool to test email deliveries in development and production. All you have to do is set mailtrap.io as an smtp server in your staging environment config:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "mailtrap.io",
   :port => 2525,
   :authentication => :plain,
   :user_name => "LOGIN",
   :password => "PASSWORD"
  }
```

Having this all your test emails sent in staging env will be stored in mailtrap for view and sharing. But non of them will be sent to the real addresses. You can use it in development as well.
And by way - it's totally free!

Comment: Absolutely handy!  Works beautifully.

Answer (score 6):

put this in your environment.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

It should stop sending mail to the mail server, I think there is a :log option, but I have not tried it out.

Comment: You probably want it in a separate `environments/staging.rb` file, though, and not in the global `environment.rb` file.

Answer (score 4):

I see people suggest using Mailtrap.io. Good alternative is [Debug Mail](http://debugmail.io/about). Using is quite simple.

Comment: Debug Mail looks like a good service functionally -- but from a security perspective I would caution developers against sending staging mail to a relatively unknown 3rd party like this.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your choices

- If you want a convenient way of receiving emails for debugging, etc. I recommend `https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web`, which will save emails locally, and provide an URL to browse emails that were sent. No email is sent outside, and you can very conveniently see the output in your browser
- If you want to be able to open email files with your email clients, you should choose a `:file` adapter for ActionMailer (configure in `config/environments/your_env.rb`)
- If you want a real production-like environment, I'd suggest to configure an email interceptor that would rewrite the TO/CC/BCC to a real mailbox of your choice, this way you can keep and test your original ActionMailer adapter

  ```
  if Rails.env.staging?
    class TestEmailsInterceptor
      def self.delivering_email(mail)
        mail.to = ['My Test Box <test-box@example.com>']
        # remove bcc, cc, etc.
      end
    end
    ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(TestEmailsInterceptor)
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

We use [maildev](http://danfarrelly.nyc/MailDev/), which you can install locally. Great for development and staging environments, easy to install in a variety of tech stacks.